# Web API AuthorizeAttribute no suitable method to override for OnAuthorization

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to make a custom AuthorizeAttribute, i've been reading some guides and they all use this method-override:

```
public class TestAuthorizeAttribute : System.Web.Http.AuthorizeAttribute
{
    public override void OnAuthorization(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {

    }
}
```

However i keep getting `no suitable method to override` for `OnAuthorization`.

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: I wasn't able to reproduce your issue. Are you sure you are using the Web API 2.2 nuget package?

Comment: try implementing IAuthorizationFilter interface. eg                            public class CustomAttribute : FilterAttribute, IAuthorizationFilter
    {
        public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
        {
            
        }
    } and decorate this custom attribute in your class and check whether this method is called